# Having trouble creating menu/selection screen with GUI (Unity3D) (C#)

Tags: unity-game-engine

What I want to do is actually very very simple, but somehow I can find a way to do it. What I am doing is im making the main menu for my game. It's very simple, basically its like all other selection screens you have at the beginnings of a game, where you can chose options, level select, ect.

Now, i'd like to add that I already have 2 apps in Google Play, so i'm not a complete beginner at programming but im not an expert either. Whats making me feel so stupid is that this should be very easy to do but I can't find a way to do it. I want the background and everything to be the same, but when you select something, say the level select, I don't want to change scenes, I just want the text on the screen to fade out and the level's to select to fade in.

What I am trying to do is give every button (level select, options, more games) a script that has a fadeOut and FadeIn funtion. When one button gets clicked, the fadeOut function is called for every button and it disables every buttons button compenent, image component, and uses .crossFadeAlpha and fades the text component to zero. Say if the player presses options, then all the buttons fade out, then if the player presses the back button, then once again all the buttons/text on the screen fade out, and the original buttons fade back in and re-enable their text, image, and button component.

This is seems very tedious to me, and i keep messing up so I want to know if there is a simple solution to this simple problem. I know this question is kinda stupid, but I just cant figure it out so i need help. thanks

Comment: Id recommend actually going through unity's tutorials and check out their gui documentation. Its well put together and pretty straight forward imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your problem: you want a clean and robust way to fade out and entire screens UI and fade in another screens UI?

My suggestion:

1. Create a single GamObject parent for all UI in your menu screen. Create a different GameObject parent for the other screens UI.
2. Add [CanvasGroup](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CanvasGroup.html) to each parent object.
3. When the button is pressed to change screens use a script to fade out parent 1 and fade in parent 2 using the CanvasGroup.alpha.

Something like this should do for the fade out/in (untested code):

```
public IEnumerator FadeScreenTransition(float fadeTime, CanvasGroup screenFrom, CanvasGroup screenTo) {
    float startTime = Time.unscaledTime;
    while (Time.unscaledTime < startTime+fadeTime) {
        float elapsed = Time.unscaledTime - startTime;
        float alpha = 1 - elapsed/fadeTime;
        screenFrom.alpha = alpha;
        yield return null;
    }
    screenFrom.alpha = 0;
    screenFrom.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    screenTo.alpha = 0;
    screenTo.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    startTime = Time.unscaledTime;
    while (Time.unscaledTime < startTime+fadeTime) {
        float elapsed = Time.unscaledTime - startTime;
        float alpha = 0 + elapsed/fadeTime;
        screenTo.alpha = alpha;
        yield return null;
    }
    screenTo.alpha = 1;
}
```